# How to start open-office headless service on a particular port in CentOS

Tags: centos, centos6, liferay, openoffice

I am trying the following to start OpenOffice headless service:

```
soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;"
```

I have tried with double-dash `--` instead of single `-` and this command just hangs and the prompt never comes:

```
soffice --headless --accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;"
```

I have installed openoffice by following [this link](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-openoffice-org-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) and it seems to be installed correctly as checked through `rpm -qa | less` which shows all the openoffice packages.

I have even tried removing it and installing again, which also completes without any error.

But the service is not getting started, I have checked through:

```
# netstat -tulpn | grep :8100
# netstat -tulpn
```

But I don't see any service listening on the port: 8100.

Can you let me know what am I doing wrong? I need this for integration with Liferay. Portal.

Environment: CentOS 6.2, 64-bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(update your OS... no excuse to be running EL6.2 *today*)

I have the [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org) (*formerly OpenOffice*) headless server running on some of my production systems for batch processing of .XLS documents.

The init script used for this is [available here](http://pastebin.com/Zcnw7zGN).

The running command line looks like the following. Port selection should be self-explanatory:

```
/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --headless --accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;
```

The necessary packages are:

```
# rpm -aq | grep libreoffice | sort
libreoffice-calc-4.0.4.2-9.el6.x86_64
libreoffice-core-4.0.4.2-9.el6.x86_64
libreoffice-headless-4.0.4.2-9.el6.x86_64
libreoffice-opensymbol-fonts-4.0.4.2-9.el6.noarch
libreoffice-pyuno-4.0.4.2-9.el6.x86_64
libreoffice-ure-4.0.4.2-9.el6.x86_64
libreoffice-writer-4.0.4.2-9.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: Thanks. What version of CentOS are you running?

Comment: We upgraded to `CentOS 6.5` and have installed `Libreoffice 4.3.2.` When I run the script it says: `ooffice: command not found`. Any inputs? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot found the way to make the command work. But I had to use `soffice` instead of `ooffice`, might be because of the version of LibreOffice. Also one more thing regarding `LibreOffice (formerly OpenOffice)`: LibreOffice is not OpenOffice. LibreOffice is built on top of OpenOffice but OpenOffice still is released separately by Apache, recently they released version 4.1.1 of AOO. Thanks

Comment: Oh, well in Red Hat's eyes, it seemed like one replaced the other.